# Autohotkey - DllCall() returning char array

Tags: c++, return, autohotkey

So I'm trying to use DllCall() in Autohotkey, I have developed a DLL in C++, i need to be able to return a buffer back to autohotkey.

In the function i have my buffer stored as "BYTE Buffer[262];" How would i return this buffer back to DllCall?

Ive tried just returning it from the function, but the variable is authotkey is still empty after a successfull call.

Example:

(DLL function)

```
void Test()
{
    BYTE buff[262]
    for(int i=0; i<262; i++)
    {
        buff[i] = 0x00;
    }
    return buff; // HOW DO I RETURN THIS TO AUTOHOTKEY
}
```

Comment: Nevermind. Fixed. need to make buff[] static... and use AStr as a return type in dllcall.(unicode)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and accept it.